# Nothing happends when running docker attach

Tags: docker

```
docker pull httpd
..
docker run -d --name MyWebServer httpd
..
docker attach MyWebServer
(nothing printed here - so I press enter + ls)
ls
(nothing printed here - so I press enter multiple times and still nothing..)
```

When I try to do the same thing with ubuntu image, it works. Why it isn't working here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the running process. With Ubuntu, you are being attached to the `sh`. With `httpd` you are being attached to the apache main process, which is not a shell.

Do this instead of attach:

```
docker exec -it MyWebServer sh
```

With that, you are launching a shell inside the same container that runs apache process.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the docs? The attach returns any messages that the container produces. I bet you wanted to do the exec instead.

It’s either

```
docker exec -it container_name_or_id bash
```

or

```
docker-compose exec service_name bash
```

if you use the docker-compose app.

You can execute any command (unless the container has no fixed entrypoint), for instance

```
docker exec container ls /
```